# Page on custom domain gives "too many redirects" error

Tags: redirect, dns, github-pages, namecheap

I have a domain from Namecheap.com and hosted a page through github pages. Sometimes the my page fails to load and gives "too many redirects" error. I think the problem in somewhere in my advanced DNS. Take a look at it-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9L9Y.png)

Basically I have got 2 A records pointing to the IP address of Github and a CNAME record pointing to mygithubusername.github.io and an URL redirect record pointing to my domain. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works perfectly for me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145231/how-to-fix-err-too-many-redirects-on-custom-github-pages-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the problem comes from the URL redirect record. When trying to reach `www.akshayud.me` it redirects to `akshayud.me` and when it hit the URL redirect it redirects back to `www.akshayud.me`, which redirects to `akshayud.me` and is making an infinite loop.

To solve it remove the URL record from the DNS (which is my preferred solution) or fix the redirection from www to root on web server level.
Here is my wget output (I used only the URL record IP to guaranty 100% usage of the URL redirect record):

```
$ wget www.akshayud.me

--2017-12-19 08:03:18--  http://www.akshayud.me/
Resolving www.akshayud.me (www.akshayud.me)... 151.101.1.147, 151.101.65.147, 151.101.129.147, ...
Connecting to www.akshayud.me (www.akshayud.me)|151.101.1.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://akshayud.me/ [following]

--2017-12-19 08:03:18--  http://akshayud.me/
Resolving akshayud.me (akshayud.me)... 162.255.119.148
Connecting to akshayud.me (akshayud.me)|162.255.119.148|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.akshayud.me/ [following]

--2017-12-19 08:03:18--  http://www.akshayud.me/
Connecting to www.akshayud.me (www.akshayud.me)|151.101.1.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://akshayud.me/ [following]

--2017-12-19 08:03:18--  http://akshayud.me/
Connecting to akshayud.me (akshayud.me)|162.255.119.148|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.akshayud.me/ [following]

--2017-12-19 08:03:19--  http://www.akshayud.me/
Connecting to www.akshayud.me (www.akshayud.me)|151.101.1.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://akshayud.me/ [following]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the solution was for me that in my github CNAME file, I had to change my webpage title. So after I changed it to "www.mywebpage.hu" (before it was without "www."), then no more redirect problems happened. I've checked your CNAME, and you don't have 'www.' too, maybe it will help if you complete your title with this.

Comment: Tried this but didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same trouble and in my case,

### How I Fixed :

the mistake was in my CNAME record. I pointed CNAME `www` to my github pages domain (username.github.io), so when I hit the domain it creates a loop of `github domain -> custom domain -> github domain .....` as github domain auto redirects to the custom domain. Changing the CNAME value to my custom domain fixed the issue